# Possibility of using java methods in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have method in java class that I need to use in kotlin. Is it possible? If so, how can I do this? 
my java class is EventCore, method name is setEvent

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

For example:

```
public class MyJava{  
    protected String value;  

    public String getValue() {  
        return value;  
    }  
}
```

Then:

```
fun main() {  
   val myJava = MyJava()  
   myJava.getValue()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance of `EventCore` class and invoke its method:

```
val eventCore = EventCore(/*pass arguments, if present*/)
eventCore.setEvent(/*pass arguments, if present*/)
```